# Injection of interface with interface properties & design principles

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have a series of classes each with several dependencies according to their role. These dependencies are being injected into the constructor. An example would be:

```
public class UserViewModel
{ 
    //...
    public UserViewModel(IDataService dataService,
                         INotificationService notificationService,
                         IDialogService dialogService,
                         INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        this.DataService = dataService;
        this.NotificationService = notificationService;
        this.DialogService = dialogService;
        this.NavigationService = navigationService;
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are several arguments to set. I could write an interface like the following:

```
public interface IInteractionService 
{
    public INotificationService NotificationService { get; set; }
    public IDialogService DialogService { get; set; }
    public INavigationService { get; set; }
}
```

and pass the injected InteractionService implementation to the UserViewModel's constructor in one piece:

```
public UserViewModel(IDataService dataService, 
       IInteractionService interactionService) {}
```

and use it like:

```
this.InteractionService.NotificationService.Publish(message);
```

Are there any issues with using an interaction interface holding interface properties in terms of design patterns/principles? Or is there a better way to look at it?

Thanks for any advice...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should not create "God" service with different services inside. It breaks Single Response Principle (SRP).

But I do not understand how it can be that DI injects you null against instance of service? May be you should fix this behaviour against creating "God" service?

Comment: Didn't realise that checking for nulls was unnecessary, thanks for that. So you reckon leave it as it is in the first snippet - injecting each service individually?

Comment: Yes. If this three services are independent, don't couple them.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, dependency injection in a constructor is a way to hell. Could you predict the final number of dependencies during the lifetime of your application? Do you really want to modify ctor's code everytime? Do you really want to initialize all dependencies at once, instead of lazy initialization?

MEF, e.g., can inject private fields in lazy manner.

You definitely shouldn't test for null injected values. If your DI-framework doesn't make these tests itself, then throw it away and use normal one.

Comment: Private field injection is more difficult to test and not so readable as constructor injection.